# Proper way to load WASM module in React for big files (more than 4kb)

Tags: reactjs, webassembly, emscripten

I'm stuck with how to load a C++ function in a React code, using wasm compiler.

My C++ is composed of two files, which result after compilation in a 160kb wasm file. Here is the command I currently use for compilation (running on macOS).

```sh
em++ ../main.cpp ../stringFormat.cpp -s WASM=1 -s EXPORT_ALL=1 -s MODULARIZE=1 -O3 --closure 1 -o lss.js -std=c++11
```

I then copy the lss and the wasm file together in my React code, in the same folder.

```js
src
  - utils
    - wasm
      lss.js
      lss.wasm
```

But then, whenever I try to import lss.js in another file, my app crashes with a bunch of undefined expressions.

*My js file*

```js
import * as lss from '../wasm/lss'
```

```
./src/utils/wasm/lss.js
  Line 10:6:     Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 11:69:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 11:117:   'read' is not defined                                                  no-undef
  Line 11:197:   'readbuffer' is not defined                                            no-undef
  Line 11:214:   'read' is not defined                                                  no-undef
  Line 11:336:   'quit' is not defined                                                  no-undef
  Line 11:367:   Unexpected use of 'print'                                              no-restricted-globals
  Line 11:430:   Unexpected use of 'print'                                              no-restricted-globals
  Line 11:493:   'printErr' is not defined                                              no-undef
  Line 12:1:     Unexpected use of 'print'                                              no-restricted-globals
  Line 12:22:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 12:26:    Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 14:307:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 23:174:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 29:10:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 29:152:   'readline' is not defined                                              no-undef
  Line 29:260:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 29:350:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 29:433:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 30:19:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
...
```

I also tried to generate standalone wasm file by adding a *SIDE_MODULE=1* flag on compilation.

```js
// My util function to load wasm file to js
const loadWebAssembly = (filename, imports = {}) =>
    WebAssembly
        .instantiateStreaming(fetch(filename), imports)
        .then(({instance}) => instance.exports);

// wasm file is now in my static folder, in public/
const lss = loadWebAssembly('wasm/lss.wasm')
    // splitIntoCommonSequences is the C++ function I try to call
    .then(module => Promise.resolve(module.splitIntoCommonSequences));

export {lss};
```

But then I got another error.

```
WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="env" error: module is not an object or function
```

I tried to figure out how to declare a proper import object for my situation without any success. Is their any better solution ? How do I know what to put inside my import object ?

Thanks !

Comment: How did you import the lss.js? Please post your code that imports lss.js.

Comment: @BumsikKim Just added above the errors, I use an import * in the file I want to use it

Comment: Good. And how did you use the module? Did you call any method of lss?

Comment: @BumsikKim I tried but actually couldn't. Even just using the lss reference, without any method, returns the exact same error.

Comment: Update: Even unused, the import statement provokes the same error.

Comment: The errors you're showing for the first compilation seem to be just warnings coming from some linter - they're not actual browser errors. As for SIDE_MODULE, it's not an option for "standalone wasm" and shouldn't be used on its own.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I figured out their were more steps to do to get WASM binary working with React, especially if you want to import it in React es6 modules (not from public folder).

I don't claim this as a general solution, just the one that worked for me (and seems to work in most cases).

**COMPILER FLAGS**

Here is the em++ build command I now use :

```sh
em++ ../main.cpp ../stringFormat.cpp \
      -Os -g1 \
      -s WASM=1 \
      -s MALLOC=emmalloc \
      -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 \
      -s EXPORT_ES6=1 \
      -s MODULARIZE=1 \
      -s 'EXPORT_NAME="LongerSubSequence"' \
      -s 'ENVIRONMENT="web"' \
      --bind \
      -o lss.mjs \
      -std=c++11 || exit 1
```

Not sure about all the options, they may be some optimization to do here. The important ones are :

- **Bind**: Apparently necessary for compiler to override C++ name mangling when naming js modules (by default, C++ compiler will change all variable names kind of like react does with css modules).
- **EXPORT_ES6**: Will slightly change the generated glue js syntax so it can be imported in es6 way.
- **MODULARIZE**: Export all functions under a common Module (named with **EXPORT_NAME** flag) so you can just import js as Module and call Module.My_CPP_Function in your js code.
- **g1**: Keep generated glue code readable enough to manage next step.

**ADDING FILES TO REACT**

The process generates two files : lss.mjs and lss.wasm. They go like this in the project tree of React :

```
My_React_Project
  |_public
  | |_/path/to/lss.wasm
  |
  |_src
    |_/path/to/lss.mjs
```

/path/to/ can be any path inside the folder, even root.

**ADAPT GLUE JS**

Finally, to fix errors, I edited the generated lss.mjs file :

1. Add `/* eslint-disable */` at top of the file, to avoid React syntax errors.
2. Replace `var _scriptDir = import.meta.url;` with `var _scriptDir = '/path/to/lss.wasm';`, relative to public folder. Not sure if it is useful regarding the following steps, but React will just crash with the import.meta syntax.
3. Replace `scriptDirectory = self.location.href;` with `scriptDirectory = window.self.location.href;`, since React es6 functions aren't binded to window.
4. Remove the following block:

```js
var dataURIPrefix = "data:application/octet-stream;base64,";

function isDataURI(filename) {
 return String.prototype.startsWith ? filename.startsWith(dataURIPrefix) : filename.indexOf(dataURIPrefix) === 0;
}
```

It is used by the compiler to automatically locate the binary file, but I handled it by myself instead.

5. replace `var wasmBinaryFile = "lss.wasm";` with `const wasmBinaryFile = '/path/to/lss.wasm';` ('/' will point to public folder).
6. Remove:

```js
if (!isDataURI(wasmBinaryFile)) {
 wasmBinaryFile = locateFile(wasmBinaryFile);
}
```

7. Remove:

```js
function getBinary() {
 try {
  if (wasmBinary) {
   return new Uint8Array(wasmBinary);
  }
  if (readBinary) {
   return readBinary(wasmBinaryFile);
  } else {
   throw "both async and sync fetching of the wasm failed";
  }
 } catch (err) {
  abort(err);
 }
}
```

8. Replace the `getBinaryPromise()` function with the following one:

```js
const getBinaryPromise = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 fetch(wasmBinaryFile, { credentials: 'same-origin' })
   .then(
     response => {
      if (!response['ok']) {
       throw "failed to load wasm binary file at '" + wasmBinaryFile + "'";
      }
      return response['arrayBuffer']();
     }
   )
   .then(resolve)
   .catch(reject);
});
```

9. A few lines below, replace

```js
if (!wasmBinary && typeof WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming === "function" && !isDataURI(wasmBinaryFile) && typeof fetch === "function")
```

with

```js
if (!wasmBinary && typeof WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming === "function" && typeof fetch === "function")
```

This just remove the isDataURI condition, since we 'trust' the path we gave to our binary file.

**NOW USE YOUR BINARY CODE**

And that's all it took for me to manage it. Now, in any of my react files, I can just use my c++ function like this :

*anyfile.js*

```js
import LongerSubSequenceGlue from 'path/to/lss.mjs';
// Avoid main function running if you just want to use another function
const lssModule = LongerSubSequenceGlue({
    noInitialRun: true,
    noExitRuntime: true
});

//...

lssModule.my_cpp_function(...my_params);
```

Worked like a charm on Chrome, Firefox and Safari, will make more test later.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. One minor point... for me when I'm initializing the module in javascript (your line `const lssModule = LongerSubSequenceGlue({`) the result is a promise, so I have to "await" it before trying to call my function.

Comment: Here is a python script to perform all the changes you have listed here automatically to the emscripten-generated .js file: https://github.com/Sheldonfrith/EmscriptenJSFileModifierScript/blob/main/script.py